# How do i validate the numbers which are multiples of 500 using regular expression?

Tags: regex, razor

The text field should accept only multiples of 500.

```
ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*(0|5)(0{2})*$/"
```

Comment: Eh, it seems that you should add `*`: `...[0-9]*...`; `"^[0-9]*((000)|(500))$"`

Comment: yeah, i tried that too. its not working

Comment: The last `*` is too much. The zeroes aren't optional are they?

Comment: zeroes are must ,minimum 2 zeroes must be there at the end. i thought to check for last 2 or 3 zeroes and 5 for last third digit. so that it will be multiple of 500.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
^\d*[05]00$
```

Which you may try [here](https://regex101.com/r/aQ4eT9/1)

Or `^\d*[05]00$|^0$` if you want to allow `0`.